# Count unique elements in a file per line

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Let's say i have a file with 5 elements on each line.

```
$ cat myfile.txt

e1 e2 e3 e4 e5
e1 e1 e2 e2 e1
e1 e1 e4 e4 e4
```

for each line i want to do the following command to count the unique elements on each line.:

```
tr \\t \\n | sort -u | wc
```

I can't figure out the first part of the command - can somebody help me?

Disclaimer: The file really looks like shown below - but  i do xargs -L 5 to get the output as shown in the first part.

```
e1
e2
e3
e4
e5
```

Comment: "unique elements on each line" or do u need "unique elements in the file"?

Comment: the number of unique on each line given i have already concatenated X lines into one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your input file:

```
$ cat file
e1 e2 e3 e4 e5
e1 e1 e2 e2 e1
e1 e1 e4 e4 e4
```

Unique elements in the file using `awk`:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]} END{for (keys in a) print keys}' 
e1
e2
e3
e4
e5
```

Unique elements in the file using `grep` instead of `tr`:

```
$ grep -Eo '\w+' file | sort -u
e1
e2
e3
e4
e5
```

---

Unique elements per line in the file:

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]; print length(a); delete a}' file
5
2
2
```

`awk` solutions really are the way to go here but using `bash` since you tagged it:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do
  echo $line | grep -Eo '\w+' | sort -u | wc -l 
done < file
```

Output:

```
5
2
2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
perl -F -lane '$count{$_}++ for (@F);print scalar values %count;undef %count' your_file
```

Tested below:

```
> cat temp
e1 e2 e3 e4 e5
e1 e1 e2 e2 e1
e1 e1 e4 e4 e4
> perl -F -lane '$count{$_}++ for (@F);print scalar values %count;undef %count' temp
5
2
2
>
```

Comment: this is for the whole file, isn't it?

Comment: your command helped me - the solution is the following: awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[$i]; print length(a)}

Comment: It works...I have changed the solution now to perl.Earlier it prints the unique elments in the file.

Comment: As you can see above i have tested it and also pasted the output.

Comment: @sarathi that doesn't prove anything, look http://ideone.com/7SG7Qz it prints `7 4 4` see @Faiz answer for a `perl` solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `perl` version if you fancy one:

```
perl -F'\s' -pane '%H=map{$_=>1}@F; $_=keys(%H)."\n"' myfile.txt
```